# Bring up existing Activity

Tags: android, loops, android-activity

I have a an app that starts with a `MapActivity` showing some POI's on the map.  There is a button to take you to a list of the POI's.  In the `ListActivity` there is a button to take you to the map.  If you start the app and click the "List" button and then the "Map" button, then the "List" button, then the "Map" button, etc.  Then you have to back out past all of those Activities in order to get to the Home screen again.  I have both activities defined as `android:launchMode="singleTop"` and I use `startActivityIfNeeded(intent, 0);` in the OnClickListener.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given Activity A and B, where  A always calls B and B always calls A:

Try calling `finish()` instead of starting A from B - which is what `onBackPressed` is doing.